# USB A 3.2 generation 2 and USB C 3.2 generation 2 ports show as 2.0

Tags: usb, motherboard, usb-c

I have a ASUS Rog Strix X570-e Gaming WiFi II motherboard with 7 x Type A and 1 x Type C ports on the back panel I/O all 3.2 gen 2.

However in USB tree viewer it shows the USB 3.1 extensible host controller with the USB 3.0 root hub expanded, 4 Type A are 3.0 support, then 3 Type A are only 2.0 support and the Type C is only 2.0 support.

Likewise, if I plug in any USB 3x device with a USB 3x cable in the affected ports, they only get recognized as 2.0. I have the latest chipset drivers and BIOS.

I had Geek Squad put together the components because I have tremors in my hands. There are 4x USB 2.0 ports at the front panel, is it possible they reversed the header accidentally so the 4X USB 2.0 ports are now in the back panel I/O, hence the 3.2 ports recognized as 2.0?

- Windows 11
- Ryzen 5800x
- Samsung 980 Pro SSD
- EVGA SUPERNOVA 1000W G+

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *is it possible they reversed the header accidentally (...)* No, totally different headers.

Comment: If they aren't different headers what could be the cause of this different USB speed if 4 of them are recognized as USB 3.2 but the other 3 type A and one type C are 2.0? Thanks for your help

Comment: If I knew I would've answered. Instead I commented to correct your hypotheses to avoid barking at the wrong tree.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks anyway

Comment: Under USB 3.10 ext. Host Contller, then USB Root Hub 3.0 Port 1-4 only show support for 2.0 then below that the Generic USB 2.0 hub shows Port 1-6 as 2.0 as it should but then Port 7-10 all show support for 3.0 with Port 8 as connector Type-C. I'm also able to connect devices in both the front and back panel I/O type C, even though I only have one Type C header. a total of 4 Port Connectors is Type C but 2 of them (the one port on the back panel I/O and the front panel I/O are USB 2.0) the other two are 3.0. How can I have 4 Type C ports w/ only one header and where are the other type c ports?

Comment: I was incorrect thinking that 4 of my 3.2 ports on the rear I/O were detected as 3.2. All of the ports are detected as 2.0. But it says companion port does support 3.0 but if I plug in of any port it never goes to one of those superspeed ports. Is it possible then that the 2.0 header was used? I saw another thread where someone did a usb selective suspend reg edit but can't find the directions, do you know how?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was self-solved due to an user case specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

After adding a selective suspend DWord value in the regedit and uninstalling and reinstalling the USB host controllers and USB root hub drivers, all my 3.2 ports are now recognized just fine in Windows.

I also disabled "turn off this device to save power" on each hub and each usb 3x devices.

There was also a couple AMD x570 chipset drivers I updated.

So one or all of these got me up and running smoothly again.